# cakephp 2 upload multiple file with data

Tags: php, file, cakephp-2.0

> I am trying to create a multiple file upload using cakephp 2. so please help. i new to cakephp
>   as you can see my controller and view coding is wokking for single image.

```
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Portfolio->create();
        $error_message = $this->Portfolio->checkFileSize($this->request->data);
        if( $error_message === true ) {
            $this->request->data['Portfolio'] = $this->Common->processMedia($this->request->data['Portfolio']);
           //echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->request->data); echo '</pre>';
           // exit();

            if ($this->Portfolio->save($this->request->data)) {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The portfolio has been saved'), 'flash_success');

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

            } else {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The portfolio could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_error');

            }

        } else {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__($error_message), 'flash_error');

        }

    }

    $talents = $this->Portfolio->Talent->find('list');


    $skills = $this->Portfolio->Skill->find('list', array(

        'order' => array('Skill.name ASC')

    ));

    $this->set(compact('talents', 'skills'));

}
```

**View** -

```
<input type="file" name="data[Portfolio][media_url_file][]" class=" validate[] m-wrap large" id="PortfolioMediaUrlFile" multiple>
```

This My database Structure
Database:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdasu.png)

genrated Array- . 
using foreach could not enable  to save this array in database .

```
Array
(
    [Portfolio] => Array
        (
            [talent_id] => 435
            [title] => asas
            [status] => Approved
            [type_of_media] => picture
            [file] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => wi-logo.png
                            [type] => image/png
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpn8ne7a
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 17457
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => unnamed.png
                            [type] => image/png
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpPcqpQw
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 14362
                        )

                )

            [media_url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => wi-logo.png
                            [type] => image/png
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpn8ne7a
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 17457
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => unnamed.png
                            [type] => image/png
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpPcqpQw
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 14362
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Are you getting error while uploading multiple images or while saving data?  Do you want to save multiple image names in a single column?

Comment: this code is for single upload .  and i want multiple upload .with multiple column.

Comment: I'm trying to use one file input element to upload multiple files. although the file picker allows selecting multiple files and creating multiple array .but then how do i save multiple array using foreach loop

Comment: Please share your final array.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working for a single upload then it can be extended to multiple.
Why not creating multiple input fields? Each file has it own input.
give each input a unique name and in the controller you can refer to the input in a loop

```
$this->request->data['Portfolio1']
$this->request->data['Portfolio2']
$this->request->data['Portfolio3']
...
```

Comment: I'm trying to use one file input element to upload multiple files. although the file picker allows selecting multiple files and creating multiple array .but then how do i save multiple array using foreach loop

Comment: Okay! So you are receiving an array with all the uploaded files?
Can you post this array

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem now.
You want save the requested data but your data contains arrays, which does not work.
So you have to create an data array which matches your db structure. 
Here I do not understand why you have 'file' and 'mediaurl' which are containing the same data. 
But here my solution:

```
$this->Portfolio->create();
for($i = 0;$i < $this->request->data['Portfolio'][file];i++){
    $dataArray = [];
    //fill in your data which will be the same for each uploaded file
    $dataArray['talen_id'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['talen_id'];
    $dataArray['title'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['title'];
    $dataArray['status'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['status'];
    $dataArray['picture'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['picture'];
    //fill in your data which is different for each uploaded file
    $dataArray['media_url'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['media_url'][$i]['name'];
    $dataArray['file'] = $this->request->data['Portfolio']['file'][$i]['name'];
    //now you can save the data
    $this->Portfolio->save($dataArray);
}
```